# How to reveal a file in file explorer

Tags: xdg-open

Is there any solution as cross-platform as xdg-open is for revealing a file in the user's file explorer?

```
xdg-open /path/to/file
```

unfortunately opens the file, but all I want to do is open the file explorer and highlight the file.

Answer (score 2):

Probably `dbus` is your best option. At least Gnome and KDE support it. Using the [ShowItems method](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/file-manager-interface/):

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 --type=method_call /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems array:string:"file:///path/to/file" string:""
```

Comment: Is there a way to reshape this so that `/path/to/file` can be its own argument at the end? I'd like to easily call it from Python https://stackoverflow.com/q/69816283/3310334

Comment: Or at least to be its own argument so I don't have to worry about sanitising the path

Comment: You might want to use a python library for that and talk to dbus directly. Anyway that's kind of out of the scope of the original question. You might want to ask a new one so that people fluent in python (and not just xdg/dbus) can chime in.