# How to reveal a file in file explorer?

Tags: python

What's a cross-platform solution I can implement in Python to reveal a file (by path) in the user's file browser?

I have working solution for windows and macOS:

```
def reveal_file(filename: str):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        opener = ['explorer',  '/select,']
    elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
        opener = ['open', '-R']
    subprocess.Popen(opener + [filename])
```

But I don't know how to support the rest of Unix and Linux. The most portable way to open a file seems to be `xdg-open file`, unfortunately it doesn't have a "reveal" option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reveal a file in file explorer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675902/how-to-reveal-a-file-in-file-explorer)

Comment: @EduardoTrápani you suggested to me on that exact question to ask a new one....

Comment: The question did look familiar :). But you keep on asking about `xdg-open`. The solution is `d-bus`. One of [these python libraries](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/#python) should do the trick for you. As the linked answer states, you just need to [send a single message to dbus from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390064/use-dbus-to-just-send-a-message-in-python). Unless you're expecting someone to write the snippet from you, these links should really help you solve the problem.